# Need to replace param from string dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, replace

Here is My function which helps me to generate links. So here in construct i am getting data from database. Now i want to generate links from db records like `http://localhost/myCrm/my_module/edit/3/1`   I know it will need string replace but i am stucked at how to do it ??

```
function getLinks(array $Links, bool $actions = true)
{
    $data = $this->data;

    /* $data will look like this.
        But it will vary on because this function will be used
        over different schema to generate the links */
    // $data = ['id'=>'1', 'module_id' => '3', 'item_id' => '1'];

    $action = "";

    if($actions && $Links)
    {
        foreach ($Links as $key => $value)
        {
            $url = "";
            // $url = "i need url replaced with the key defined in '{}' from $data[{key}] "

            $action .= '<a href="'.$url.'" >'.$value['text'].'</a>';
        }
    }
}



$Links = [
    [
        'text'  =>  'Edit'
        'url'   =>  base_url('my_module/edit/{module_id}/{item_id}')
    ]
];
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: And what about `str_replace`?

Comment: It won't work here as i will replace the column name from the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > In this case you will need to use `preg_replace_callback` function. In `preg_replace_callback` you can pass closure and make effective changes by getting matches. you can get match from $matches passed in closure

```
//Your code will look like this
if($actions && $Links)
{
    foreach ($Links as $key => $value)
    {
        $url = preg_replace_callback(

            "/(?:\{)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:\})/",

            function($matches) use($data)
            {
                return $data[$matches[1]];
            },

            $value['url']
        );

        $action .= '<a href="'.$url.'" >'.$value['text'].'</a>';
    }
}
```

**in this regex `(?:\{)` represents non capturing group. It means that match will be performed but it will not be captured. so it will match the `module_id` and `item_id` from the string so you can get the index here and replace with your data.**

Comment: Thank you so much pratik. That's exactly same thing i wanted. Thank you so much for your answer.